# Posting Article from PHP website to Google Plus

Tags: php, yii, google-plus, google-plus-domains

I am working on PHP website built with Yii 1 framework.
I want to make articles auto posted to Google Plus business page related to the website.

1. I create test business page on Google Plus related to my Google account and website I work on.
2. I can authorize myself by getting access token using OAuth2 (authorization of users, I think it's done).
3. Now how can I use this access token to post articles from PHP website to Google Plus?

I started from here https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/pages-signup but what is the next step after I complete this form?
How can my PHP code interact with this API?
What request should I send to post to API?

Comment: Google will contact you if they give you access.   That beta is extremely limited I have never heard of anyone besides very large companies getting access.   If you do get access they will probably contact you.

Comment: Thank you,the same issue  for  google plus personal account?

Comment: It is not possible to post to Google+ the social media website.  The Google plus api is read only.